# Wick theorem on correlator in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, path-integral, wick-theorem

I have an exercise to calculate the following one dimensional integral explicitly using the Wick theorem:

$$\langle q(t_1)q(t_2)q(t_3)q(t_4)q(t_5)q(t_6)\rangle=\frac{\int Dq \,q(t_1)q(t_2)q(t_3)q(t_4)q(t_5)q(t_6)e^{-S_E} }{\int Dq\,e^{-S_E}}$$
where
$$S_E=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\Big(\frac{1}{2}\dot{q}^2+\frac{m^2q^2}{2}  \Big)dt. $$
I know what the answer is going to be as it is just using Wick theorem. But as the problem is to explicitly calculate, I assume that I actually need to calculate the integral myself.

This is what I have done:
$$\int Dq \,q(t_1)q(t_2)q(t_3)q(t_4)q(t_5)q(t_6)e^{-S_E}
=\left. \frac{\delta}{\delta f(t_1)}\cdots\frac{\delta}{\delta f(t_6)}\int e^{-S_E+\int\! dt~ fq}\right|_{f=0} . $$

I need some help in how to proceed from here.

Comment: From there is a gaussian integral. The expoent is quadratic in q. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: I think so,  I get $\sqrt{2\pi}$?

Comment: It's wrong. I'm sorry that I'm not able to write a better answer now. I'm traveling  and without complete access to internet. Please, take a look at harmonic oscillator propagator. Wikipedia may suffice. In time, if you haven't solved it or someone hasn't posted something, I will write a complete answer.

Comment: I look it up and I can solve the integral now, thanks.  Do you think I interpreted the exercise correctly? I am still a bit unsure about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for the delay.

I will work with integrals defined on $\mathbf{R}^{n}$.
A path integral can be thought as the limit $n \to  \infty$.
Generalizations to complex numbers are also straightforward.

**Notation.**

I will use the summation convention. Every repeated index is summed over.
For example,

$$
\sum_{i,j=1}^{n} x_{i} A_{ij} x_{j} \text{ is written as }
x_{i} A_{ij} x_{j}.
$$

**Gaussian Integrals.**

Consider the integral

$$
Z(A) = \int d^{n} x \, \exp\left( - \frac{1}{2} x_{i} A_{ij} x_{j} \right).
$$

It converges if the eigenvalues of A are non-negative and non-vanishing. One can also prove that

$$ 
Z(A) = ( 2 \pi )^{n/2} \left( \det A \right)^{-1/2}.
$$

by several methods. A possible way is to consider an orthogonal transformation which diagonalizes $A$, such that

$$
A = O D O^{T} , \quad O^{T} O = 1 \quad \text{and} \quad D_{ij} = a_{i} \delta_{ij}
$$

where $a_{i}$ are the eigenvalues of $A$. The integral factorizes because

$$
x_{i} A_{ij} x_{j} = x_{i} O_{ik} a_{k} O_{jk} x_{j} = a_{i} y_{i}^{2}
$$

for $y_{i} = O_{ij} x_{j}$. And it converges to

$$
Z(A) = \Pi_{i=1}^{n} \int dy_{i} e^{-a_{i} y_{i}^{2}/2} 
= (2 \pi)^{n/2} (a_{1} a_{2} \cdots a_{n})^{-1/2} = (2 \pi)^{n/2} (\det A)^{-1/2}.
$$

Of special interest is the case

$$
Z(A,b) = \int d^{n}x \exp \left( - \frac{1}{2} x_{i} A_{ij} x_{j} + b_{i} x_{i} \right)
$$

which gives

$$
Z(A, b) = (2 \pi)^{n/2} (\det A)^{-1/2} \exp \left[ \frac{1}{2} b_{i} \Delta_{ij} b_{j} \right]
$$

where $\Delta$ is the inverse of $A$ (prove this result yourself. Hint: Consider the change of variables

$$
x_{i} = \Delta_{ij} b_{j} + y_i
$$

from $x_{i}$ to $y_{i}$).

**Wick Theorem.**

A Gaussian integrand can be considered a probability distribution. We can use it to calculate expectation values:

$$
\langle F(x) \rangle = N \int d^{n} x \, F(x) \, \exp \left( - \frac{1}{2}
x_{i} A_{ij} x_{j} \right)
$$

and the constant $N$ is determined from the condition $\langle 1 \rangle = 1$.
It is

$$
N = Z^{-1}(A, 0) = (2 \pi)^{-n/2} (\det A)^{1/2}. 
$$

The function

$$
Z(A,b)/Z(A,0) = \langle e^{b_{i} x_{i}} \rangle    
$$

is then the generating function of the moments of distribution. Expectation values are obtained by differentiating with respect to $b_{i}$:

$$
\langle x_{k_{1}} \cdots x_{k_{l}} \rangle =
\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial b_{k_{1}}} \cdots \frac{\partial}{\partial b_{k_{l}}}
\right) \exp\left[ \frac{1}{2} b_{i} \Delta_{ij} b_{j} \right] |_{b=0}.
$$

This can be inspected by expanding both sides of the generating function in powers of $b_{i}$.

If $F(x)$ is polynomial in $x$, then

$$
\langle F(x) \rangle = F\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial b} \right) 
\exp \left[ \frac{1}{2} b_{i} \Delta_{ij} b_{j} \right]|_{b=0}.
$$

This is known as Wick's theorem. Each time one differentiates the exponential, one gets a factor of $b$. Since $b$ is set to zero at the end, one must differentiate this factor of $b$ later, otherwise the corresponding contribution vanishes.

Thus, the expectation value, in a Gaussian theory, is given by all the possible ways of pairing the indices $k_{1}$ to $k_{l}$ in $\Delta_{k_{i} k_{j}}$. One finds, successively,

$$
\langle x_{i_1} x_{i_2} \rangle = \Delta_{i_{1} i_{2}} ,
$$

$$
\langle x_{i_{1}} x_{i_{2}} x_{i_{3}} x_{i_{4}} \rangle =
\Delta_{ i_{1} i_{2} } \Delta_{i_{3} i_{4}} + 
\Delta_{i_{1} i_{3} } \Delta_{i_{2} i_{4}} + 
\Delta_{i_{1} i_{4}} \Delta_{i_{2} i_{3}}.
$$

EDIT.

**Quantum Mechanics.**

You can now make the substitution $x_{i} \mapsto x(t)$. So instead of using vectors and partial derivatives, you will need functions and functional differentiation.

Of ultimate importance is $\Delta$, which is now called propagator. It was defined via

$$
A_{ij} \Delta_{jk}  = \delta_{ik}
$$

and now is interpreted in the continuum limit:

$$ 
A \Delta(t-t') = \delta (t - t'),
$$

where $A$ is the quadratic piece in the Lagrangian. In your case

$$
A = \frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}} + \omega^{2}.
$$

In the literature, this $\Delta$ is known as the Green function.

I have given you all ingredients so that you can do this exercise.
Hope this gives you some insight.

Answer (score 0):

I find useful the following alternative proof to that of OkThen. I learned it from https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.1554. In the same finite dimensional setting we have
$$0=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\text{d}^nx\, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\left(e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^kA_{kl}x^l}x^{i_1}\cdots x^{i_n}\right)\\=-A_{ij}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\text{d}^nx\, e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^kA_{kl}x^l}x^jx^{i_1}\cdots x^{i_n}+\sum_{r=1}^n\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\text{d}^nx\, e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^kA_{kl}x^l}x^{i_1}\cdots\hat{x^{i_r}}\cdots x^{i_n}\\=-A_{ij}\langle x^jx^{i_1}\cdots x^{i_n}\rangle+\sum_{r=1}^n\langle x^{i_1}\cdots\hat{x^{i_r}}\cdots x^{i_n}\rangle.$$
Denoting the inverse matrix by upper indices, we obtain
$$\langle x^ix^{i_1}\cdots x^{i_n}\rangle=\sum_{r=1}^nA^{ii_r}\langle x^{i_1}\cdots\hat{x^{i_r}}\cdots x^{i_n}\rangle.$$

Wick's theorem can then be obtained by induction from this formula: "Contract the first term of the correlation function with all the other terms, rinse and repeat."